# Vim UltiSnips - 2 File Types for 1 Snippet File

Tags: vim, code-snippets, macvim, ultisnips

Can I map two file types to one snippet file?

For example, I would like both `.html` and `.ctp` files to use the `hmtl.snippets` file.

If not, would a sym link from the operating system do the trick?

Or can I create a global snippet file for all file types?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can (at the very least):

- use a symlink
- duplicate `html.snippets` and rename it to `ctp.snippets`
- add your general snippets to `_.snippets`
- add `autocmd BufEnter,BufNew *.ctp setf ctp.html` to your `~/.vimrc`

Comment: Awesome!  Thanks for the superb answer!  _.snippets will be very handy!

Comment: ultisnips use all.snippets for general text snippets

Answer (score 10):

What romainl said. Additionally, you could create a `ctp.snippets` file and put an `extends html` command in it. All of this is well documented in UltiSnips' vimhelp.

Comment: A very useful feature.  I will certainly extend html.